WebSocket streaming to Azure Text-to-Speech failing with "Input stream cannot be null"
Problem
I'm implementing real-time text-to-speech streaming using Azure's WebSocket API in Node.js. The WebSocket connection establishes successfully but immediately closes with an error when sending the initial SSML message.
Error Output
WebSocket connection established
--------------open done------------------
Received message: X-RequestId:13604750-2bxd-42a2-b523-cdesadas3d47
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Path:turn.start

{
  "context": {
    "serviceTag": "9a23ce3549axdf7ddfg1d42317bcx5210"
  }
}
WebSocket connection closed with code 1007. Reason: Input stream cannot be null

Current Implementation
Here's the relevant part of the code (full source available here):
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import axios from 'axios';
import crypto from 'crypto';

async function streamTextToSpeech(textStream) {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken();
  const ws = new WebSocket(
    `wss://${region}.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/websocket/v2?Authorization=Bearer ${accessToken}`
  );

  ws.on('open', () => {
    // Send configuration message
    const configMessage = {
      context: {
        synthesis: {
          audio: {
            metadataOptions: {
              sentenceBoundaryEnabled: 'false',
              wordBoundaryEnabled: 'false'
            },
            outputFormat: 'audio-24khz-48kbitrate-mono-mp3'
          },
          language: {
            autoDetection: false
          },
          voice: {
            languageId: 'en-US',
            name: 'en-US-JennyNeural'
          }
        }
      }
    };
    
    const configMessageString = `Content-Type:application/json\r\nPath:speech.config\r\n\r\n${JSON.stringify(configMessage)}`;
    ws.send(configMessageString);

    // This is where the error occurs
    const initialSsml = `<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='en-US-JennyNeural'>Initializing speech synthesis.</voice></speak>`;
    const initialMessage = `Path:ssml\r\nX-RequestId:${crypto.randomUUID()}\r\nContent-Type:application/ssml+xml\r\n\r\n${initialSsml}`;
    ws.send(initialMessage);
  });

  // Error handling and message processing code...
}

Environment

Node.js: 14.17.0
ws: 8.2.3
axios: 0.24.0
Azure Cognitive Services API: v2

Questions

What's causing the "Input stream cannot be null" error when sending the initial SSML message?
Is the WebSocket message format correct for Azure TTS API?
Are there specific requirements for SSML formatting when using the WebSocket API?

What I've Tried

Verified WebSocket connection parameters and authentication
Double-checked SSML formatting according to Azure documentation
Confirmed the access token is valid and properly formatted
Attempted to locate the Python SDK source code to understand the implementation details, but couldn't find the repository or source files

References

Azure Speech Service Documentation on Low Latency Synthesis (Note: primarily covers Python SDK)
Full Source Code

Looking for help debugging this WebSocket implementation or examples of correct message formatting for Azure's TTS WebSocket API.

Have you checked the key and region are correct?

Yes, the key and region are correct; otherwise, I would expect a 401 error when trying to connect to the WebSocket, and the WebSocket connection established log would never show up.

Try to decrease the text in the sentence you are trying to convert to speech.

I tried the below code to convert text-to-speech using Websocket and successfully got the streamed audio output to a .wav file.
Code :
server.js :
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const AZURE_SPEECH_KEY = '<speech_key>';
const AZURE_SERVICE_REGION = '<speech_region>';

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    console.log('New client connected');
    ws.on('message', async (message) => {
        console.log(`Received message from client: ${message}`);
        const { text, voice_name } = JSON.parse(message);
        try {
            const audioBuffer = await textToSpeech(text, voice_name);
            const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'kam.wav'); 
            fs.writeFileSync(filePath, audioBuffer);
            console.log(`Audio saved to ${filePath}`);
            ws.send(audioBuffer); 
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            ws.send("Failed to generate audio.");
        }
    });
    ws.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
});
app.post('/synthesize', (req, res) => {
    res.status(405).send("Use WebSocket to synthesize text to speech.");
});

async function textToSpeech(text, voiceName = 'en-US-JennyNeural') {
    const url = `https://${AZURE_SERVICE_REGION}.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1`;
    const headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': AZURE_SPEECH_KEY,
        'Content-Type': 'application/ssml+xml',
        'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat': 'riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm',
    };
    const ssml = 
    `<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'>
        <voice xml:lang='en-US' name='${voiceName}'>${text}</voice>
    </speak>`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, ssml, { headers, responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
    return response.data;
}

public/index.html :
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Text to Speech</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text to Speech</h1>
    <form id="ttsForm">
        <label for="text">Enter Text:</label><br>
        <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br><br>
        
        <label for="voice_name">Voice Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="voice_name" name="voice_name" value="en-US-JennyNeural" required><br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Convert to Speech">
    </form>
    <script>
        let socket;
        function initWebSocket() {
            socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');
            socket.onopen = () => {
                console.log('WebSocket connection established');
            };
            socket.onmessage = (event) => {
                console.log('Message from server: ', event.data);
                if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
                    const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
                    const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
                    audio.play();
                } else {
                    console.error('Received non-audio message:', event.data);
                }
            };
            socket.onclose = () => {
                console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
            };
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            initWebSocket();

            document.getElementById('ttsForm').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                sendMessage();
            });
        });
        function sendMessage() {
            const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            const voiceName = document.getElementById('voice_name').value;
            const message = JSON.stringify({ text, voice_name: voiceName });
            socket.send(message);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Browser Output :
I successfully converted the text-to-speech on the web and got the streamed audio output saved to a .wav file.

Output :
The text-to-speech converted output was saved to the below location after streaming.


I am trying to make a WebSocket connection to Azure from the "textToSpeech" function, rather than from the frontend to the server.
My goal is to send audio generated from GPT to Azure only from the server side.
Do you think the "textToSpeech()" function inside server.js could be modified to use a WebSocket connection instead of a POST method?
